# Visual Studio 2019 Code formatting stops when using .jsx

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, jsx, visual-studio-2019

I have been experiencing some problems with Visual Studio 2019 and code formatting with `.jsx` files. For some reason the code formatting will simply stop working, and seems to only happen with `.jsx` files.

It is immediately apparent when this happens, in the code editor there are reference lines that show the indentation, when the formatting and intellisense stop working these disappear. When VS is restarted only the visible or top-most `.jsx` file code formatting will be working, all the other files that are left open will not. The only way I have found to get this restarted is to close and reopen the file, then everything works.

This can be a pain since I prefer to use the pinned tab function and multiple editors (multiple monitors), could this be part of the cause, maybe a bug? This problem seems to happen intermittently and I can't figure out what is causing this to stop working.

Is there a command to force VS to reexamine the open files and restart the formatting? I have tried disabling `Track changes` in `Tools->Options->Text Editor` without any luck, is there possibly another setting that I need to turn on/off that might be causing this?

I am running a fresh install of everything (just put in a new HDD), I have not installed any other versions of VS and the only extensions that I have installed are the ones that are included in the `Web Essentials` package.